# метод бинарного поиска в задаче с выводом информации из файла

Tags: c++, алгоритм, поиск

Дан текстовый файл со словами. С клавиатуры вводится слово. Необходимо произвести бинарный поиск всех слов в тексте, которые содержат возможные перестановки букв в введённом слове.

Подскажите, как именно тут должен работать бинарный поиск (каков алгоритм) ?

Comment: Бинарный поиск здесь работает как и обычно. Вам нужен, понятно, предварительно отсортированный список слов из текста.

Comment: @VladD ,  а по какому признаку сортировать эти слова ?

Comment: @lol2014: Например, лексикографически. Впрочем, строки и сами умеют лексикографически сравниваться. Попробуйте сами! `s1 < s2`. (Я имею в виду `std::string`, конечно.)